# Regex to remove junk from a .txt file in Unix

Tags: unix

I am new to Unix.
I am using a sed command to remove junk from a .txt file in Unix.
This is the command that i used--

```
sed -e 's/[^ -~]//g' final.txt > file1_now
```

but here i am facing a problem the junks are getting removed, but in case my data contains a '-' that is also removed. I dont want that.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Binayak

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
sed -e 's/[^ ~-]//g' final.txt > file1_now
```

The `-` character **must** be the latest (or the first) in your character class, because the meaning is different in other cases : it means a range like in `[a-z]`

---

> The - character is treated as a literal character if it is the last or the first (after the ^) character within the brackets: [abc-], [-abc].

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: The hyphen is used for character ranges in character classes.  `[A-DF]` is equivalent to `[ABCDF]`. So, for a hyphen to stand for itself, either it must have nothing before it or nothing after it.  The caret for negation is at the front, so the hyphen has to go at the end.